# Changing color of sprites with colorBlendFactor

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have a loop making a cluster of spriteNodes. It is a crowd of people. The sprites are just plain white textures as research told me don't use black ones when using colorBlendFactor.

I also have an extension for UIColor with a bunch of my own colors.
When I use the following code to set the colors of the sprite it works just fine.

```
    let colorArray = [UIColor.red,
                      UIColor.yellow,
                      UIColor.gray,
                      UIColor.cyan]
    let rndColour = colorArray[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(colorArray.count - 1)))]
    person.color = rndColour
    person.colorBlendFactor = 0.6
```

However, when I populate colorArray with my custom colors, the sprites just appear white. I have tried colorBlendFactor = 1 and mixing custom colors with standard ones and only the standard ones will work.

What is the reason behind this?

Comment: Please, and sorry, need to see the extension that makes your custom colours to understand what the problem(s) might be.

Comment: Thanks, as soon as I read this it clicked

Comment: Glad it helped! I'm a maker of much more rookie mistakes than you'll ever manage. ConstantlyKickingMySelf was an avatar naming option before I settled for "Confused"

Answer (score 2):

Well as soon as Confused requested to see the extension, the penny dropped. Rookie error.

My extensions looked like this:

```
extension UIColor {

    public class var maroon: UIColor {
        return UIColor(red: 105, green: 14, blue: 58, alpha: 1)
    }
}
```

As these colors should be between 0 and 1, they must be divided by 255... the maximum color. And so they should look like this.

```
extension UIColor {

    public class var maroon: UIColor {
        return UIColor(red: 105/255, green: 14/255, blue: 58/255, alpha: 1)
    }
}
```

I should probably take a break more often...